# Why isn't Android Studio showing widget elements on mouse click?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-widget

I saw a video tutorial on flutter coding, of mouse clicking on a widget showing additional information about widgets. Details of that are shown below.

[image]

But when I wrote the same code in Android Studio, it didn't show me that additional information. Why is that, and how can I change it?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio Goto

```
 File->Settings->Editor->General
```

and Enable

```
Show quick documentation on mouse move.
```

[image: You can see the screenshot below]